# How to rewrite url with . in the path?

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site (asp.net), somehow the google thinks it has url like this:

```
http://www.example.com/IL/Venice/Industrial-Warehouse-Space/1226-Bissell-Ave./709265
```

the actual url should be

```
http://www.example.com/IL/Venice/Industrial-Warehouse-Space/1226-Bissell-Ave/709265
```

or http://www.example.com/property.aspx?id=709265

How to rewrite it?

I tried several software to rewrite this, i.e. ISAPI_Rewrite3.0,

```
#RewriteRule /[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]/[a-zA-Z0-9\-/,.`')(&_@%\.]+./([0-9]+) /Property.aspx?ID=$1 [L]
```

However, it did not work. It returns a 404. Although the customError is setup, but never hit it.

It almost looks like before the asp.net process it, it returns 404.

Answer (score 0):

These are two questions (and rules), I think. One is to redirect the first URL (with `.`) to the second (*without* `.`).

```
RewriteRule ^(../.+?)\.(/[^/]+)$ /$1$2 [R,L]
```

The other is to rewrite from a request URI to your ASP script.

The rewrite rule has several problems

- It starts with a slash, which is not there in a directory context
- It has a `.` in front of the last slash, which is neither necessary nor helpful
- The target is capitalized, which may result in a "404 Not found", if the file system is case sensitive
- The query parameter `ID` is uppercase, this may or may not be a problem

If you just want to pick up the trailing number as an id for your script, and don't really care about the format of your URL, you may try to capture it with this rule

```
RewriteRule ^.+?/([0-9]+)$ /property.aspx?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: no, this does not work. it still shows as "Resource cannot be found", the customError page can not capture this. I started to think that iis somehow process the url before anything else because the url has './'

Comment: I missed the IIS part, and thought this question is about Apache's mod_rewrite, because it is tagged [tag:.htaccess] and [tag:mod-rewrite].

Comment: rewrite rule should be same, just regular expression, but IIS and Apache may have difference to process this.